# Search and Replace using GREP

Tags: shell, unix, sed, grep

I have a big file with mixed serialised and unserialised data. In this data there are multiple URLs which have different paths but the domain is same. These URLs are incorrect, however their filenames are right.

For example:

https://cloudflarexyz.com/2012/assets/images/File-A.jpg
https://cloudflarexyz.com/2015/assets/images/File-B.jpg

So File-A.jpg and File-B.jpg are correct - but their paths + domain names are wrong.

i.e.,
in the URL [https://cloudflarexyz.com/2012/assets/images/File-A.jpg “https://cloudflarexyz.com/2012/assets/images/”](https://cloudflarexyz.com/2012/assets/images/File-A.jpg%E2%80%A8%E2%80%9Chttps://cloudflarexyz.com/2012/assets/images/%E2%80%9D) part is wrong.

I have another file which has the correct names and URLs of the files.

i.e.,  https://correct-url.com/assets/File-A.jpg.

I am trying to grep that big file with wrong URLs using pattern match which targets the pattern of the domain and image file types as follows.

`$(grep -oE ‘https?://[^ ]+cloudflarexyz.com[^ ]+.(jpgjpeg|png|gif)’ bigfile.txt`

After this I am trying to loop through each result, for each result I am getting the file name and searching for the correct URL in my other file.

```
while read -r line; do
    # Following splits the URL by a forward slash and returns just the file name.
    broken_image_name=$(line##*/)
    # If there are more than one paths in correct URLs list, following will return just the last one. 
    correct_url=“$(grep $broken_image_name correct-paths.txt | tail -1 )
    
done;
```

I have two problems  A: This does not work for serialised data.
B: I am not sure how should I use `sed` to replace the URLs in that big file.   Any help is highly appreciated.   Thanks

I am thinking to first split the serialised data using `\` as delimiter, and then parsing the data but even if I do that, I am not sure how would I replace the URLs.

Comment: If the correct URLs list contains more than one paths, how do we associate the
wrong path with the correct path? What do you mean by the term `serialised` ?
It will be helpful if you can provide a minimal example of actual files including
the `serialised` data and multiple correct paths. BR.

Comment: I have 100% confidence in correct URLs list and I am doing ```tail -1``` because I want the last path from those multiple paths. I.e., if correct list outputs 3 paths for a file FILEA I want the last path.

When I say serialised I mean JSON. It's a SQL file with JSON and non-json data.

Comment: If you need to process JSON data, consider to use JSON parse tool such as `jq`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your `grep` command has a typo in it. `grep -oE 'https?://[^ ]+cloudflarexyz.com[^ ]+.(jpgjpeg|png|gif)' bigfile.txt` will capture only URLs that end in `.gif` or `.png` or `.jpgjpeg`. The pattern also will not match the URLs you supplied that begin with `https://cloudfl...` because you've required (with the `+` quantifier) that at least one non-space character occur after the second `/`. Use `*` instead of `+` to match zero or more characters.

You probably meant to say:

```
grep -oE 'https?://[^ ]*cloudflarexyz.com[^ ]+.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)' bigfile.txt`
```

or even:

```
grep -oE 'https?://[^ ]*cloudflarexyz.com[^ ]+.(jpe?g|png|gif)' bigfile.txt`
```

If there's a particular character that you know will never occur in any of these URLs, you can use that character instead of `/` as the delimiter to the `s` command in sed. A space should never occur in a URL, so you could add

```
sed -i "s $line $correct_url g" bigfile.txt
```

to the end of your `while` loop as-is. The only issue I can see with this with URLs is that sed will match any single character (rather than a literal `.`) when seeing a `.` in `$line`, but I'm assuming you don't have `$broken_image_name`s that would cause that to be problem. For very simple patterns it's unlikely that you need to escape anything at all.

There are also some missing quotes in your script.

```
correct_url=“$(grep $broken_image_name correct-paths.txt | tail -1 )
```

should have a quote at the end of line. I am also not sure about that `“` character. Just use plain unoriented quotes, `"` and `'`.

I also am pretty sure this would not work, unless this is some shell dialect I am not familiar with:

```
broken_image_name=$(line##*/)
```

should be:

```
broken_image_name="${line##*/}"
```

(with curly braces).

A good sanity check in general in shell-scripting is to wrap all references to variables in double quotes *unless* you specifically want them to be split into words; in this case you shouldn't have spaces in your variables, but

```
grep "$broken_image_name" correct-paths.txt
```

is better form than the unquoted form.

Good luck and be sure to back up `bigfile.txt` before running the script.